# Merge 2 data.tables with more than one column the data.table way

Tags: r, data.table

I have two `data.table`s as following:-

```
a <- data.table(id = 1:10, val = 2010:2019)
b <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 4, 6), year = 1:4)
```

Now if I merged `b` and `a` as following:-

```
b[a, val := i.val, on = "id"]
```

This will make an extra column in `b` called `val`. This will also not reassign the memory for `b` `data.table`.

I wanted to know if `a` more than 2 columns and was as following:-

```
    a <- data.table(id = 1:10, val = 2010:2019,
                    twr = c(10, 13, 22 ,43, 23, 23, -4, 33, -54, 34))
```

how to merge the two `data.table`s (`b` and `a`), the `data.table` way, i.e. not using `merge` or any of the `join` function.

But using `[, , on = "id"]` syntax.

I want to know this because using any of the `join` functions or `merge` makes a whole new object, whereas the `data.table` way only creates the new columns and not a whole new object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only two columns to be returned, just wrap then in a `list` (or short form `.(`) after joining `on` by 'id', and assign `:=`) those columns to 'b'

```
b[a, names(a)[-1] := .(i.val, i.twr), on = .(id)]
```

---

If there are many columns to be returned

```
nm1 <- names(a)[-1]
b[a, (nm1) := mget(paste0("i.", nm1)), on = .(id)]
```

-ouput

```
b
   id year  val twr
1:  1    1 2010  10
2:  2    2 2011  13
3:  4    3 2013  43
4:  6    4 2015  23
```

Answer (score 0):

With development version 1.14.1, [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) has gained the `env` parameter which is meant for *programming on data.table*:

```
cols <- setdiff(names(a), "id")
b[a, on = "id", (cols) := acols, env = list(acols = as.list(cols))][]
```

> ```
>    id year  val twr
> 1:  1    1 2010  10
> 2:  2    2 2011  13
> 3:  4    3 2013  43
> 4:  6    4 2015  23
> ```

This will work in many cases where there no duplicate column names in  `a` and `b` except those to join on. However, we can explicitely refer to columns of `a` by using the prefix `i.`:

```
b[a, on = "id", (cols) := acols, env = list(acols = as.list(paste0("i.", cols)))][]
```